# How do you enable MouseKeys without using the mouse?

Tags: system-settings, accessibility, mouse-keys

Recently, I had to shut down a Mac with no mouse and only a PC keyboard with no Eject key.  (Incidentally, there are several solutions to that puzzle, and the one I settled on was to use the Terminal.) But as I first approached the problem, I thought: There is some universal access feature there to help if one can't use the mouse, isn't there? Yes: MouseKeys.  However, [this nice page with the keyboard shortcuts for MouseKeys in Lion](http://support.apple.com/kb/ph4390) suggests that you have to enable a checkbox in a System Preferences pane before you can use it. So, how do you enable MouseKeys without using a mouse?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the same menus and buttons you would if you were turning on MouseKeys using the mouse, but using them from the keyboard instead. There are a lot of standard keyboard shortcuts that you can use to navigate around without the mouse:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> to go to the Apple menu
- Arrow keys and <kbd>Return</kbd> to choose an item from the pull down menus
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> to cycle through the sections of a window
- <kbd>Tab</kbd> to cycle through the controls in a section, and <kbd>Space</kbd> to use the highlighted button or checkbox.

[This guide from the BBC's site](http://www.bbc.co.uk/accessibility/guides/keyboard_mouse/computer/mac/os_x/#setup) puts it all together.